# Java convert millisecond timestamp to date with respect to given timezone

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting, timezone-offset

I have seen many resources on this but one thing I cant get is when converting the millisecond timestamp, how I add a corresponding time zone, during the conversion process.

```
Date date = new Date(Long.valueOf(dateInMil*1000L);
SimpleDateFormat myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, ''yy");
String formatted = myDate.format(date);
```

Now if I have a time zone/offset in string formate i.e. "-04:00" or "+2:00" how to apply it to the above so I can get the proper date ?

Comment: Why are you converting milliseconds into microseconds? Is `dateInMil` actually seconds?

Comment: Note: If you are using Java 8, you should **not** be using `Date` or `Calendar` objects, and instead using `LocalDate`, for example

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting. These issues have been covered many times already.

Comment: You are really asking two questions in one and should instead post them as two questions: how to parse an offset like `"-04:00"` and how to convert milliseconds to date at a given offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was doing a similar thing in my previous project.You can use setTimeZone method of SimpleDateFormat class. Something like this :

```
mydate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT -0400"));
```

Comment: Theoretically, if you insist on using the outmoded classes, this should be the correct solution. However, no matter if I put `GMT -1400` or `GMT +1400`, I still get the same date. The old classes are more troublesome than one would think. I discourage using them. Use `java.time` instead.

Comment: I will mark your solution as accepted since its the way I started with and what worked for me, but for some reason didn't work earlier, when used it first time.

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( myCountOfMilliseconds ) 
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )
       .toString()
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes rather than the troublesome old `Calendar`/`Date` classes that are now legacy.

Assuming your count of milliseconds is a count since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (1970-01-01T00:00), then parse as a `Instant`.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( myCountOfMilliseconds ) ;
```

To move from [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) to another time zone, apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

### Objects vs text

After assigning the time zone, *then* generate a string in your desired format (not before). You may be conflating date-time values (objects) with strings representing their value textually. Learn to think of smart objects, not dumb strings.

### `DateTimeFormatter`

To generate a String in a particular format, use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Search Stack Overflow as this been covered many many times, as have the other concepts shown here. Of special note are the [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDateTime-java.time.format.FormatStyle-) methods.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
    DateTimeFormatter myDateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, MMM d, ''yy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    long dateInSec = 1_554_321_098L;
    String utcOffsetString = "-04:00";
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of(utcOffsetString);
    String date = Instant.ofEpochSecond(dateInSec)
            .atOffset(offset)
            .format(myDateFormatter);
    System.out.println(date);
```

This prints

```
Wed, Apr 3, '19
```

The other example offset you gave, `+2:00`, is slightly more difficult since `ZoneOffset.of` requires either only hours (`+2`) or two-digit hours before the colon (`+02:00`). One solution is to fix the string before handing it to `ZoneOffset`:

```
    String utcOffsetString = "+2:00";
    utcOffsetString = utcOffsetString.replaceFirst("([-+])(\\d:\\d{2})", "$10$2");
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of(utcOffsetString);
```

The result is still `Wed, Apr 3, '19`. If there were already 2-digit hours in the string, `replaceFirst` won’t replace anything, so you just get the same string back.

If I change the offset to `+08:00`, I get `Thu, Apr 4, '19` instead.

Edit: I frankly find the regular expression I use for fixing the offset string quite unreadable. Here’s a simpler way of fixing it:

```
    DateTimeFormatter offsetFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("O", Locale.ENGLISH);
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.from(offsetFormatter.parse("GMT" + utcOffsetString));
```

Like Basil Bourque I am using [`java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). See all the details in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48716755/5772882).

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what your looking for but close

```
String timeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE MMMMM d hh:mm a");
sdf.setTimeZone(tz);

Date localizedTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

If you keep the localization strings instead of the offsets this will work.  Or you can make a map.